# Java change background color png image

Tags: java, image, graphics, graphics2d

I have been following some StackOverflow links using Graphics2D to change the background color of a BufferedImage.

The project I am working on requires that I read in a png image from a given url; the png image retrieved has a transparent background, and I would like to set it to white.

Here is what I have:

```
String u = this.format() ;
        BufferedImage image = null ;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(u) ;
            image = ImageIO.read(url) ;
            Graphics2D graphics = image.createGraphics() ;
            graphics.setBackground(Color.WHITE) ;
            graphics.clearRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()) ;


            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(outPath + fileName)) ;
            graphics.dispose() ;

        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace() ;
        }
```

The problem I am running into is that when I view the image, the image appears as a solid white box. Apparently I have overlaid a white background on top of the existing image that I retrieved.

How can I preserve the original image and only change the background? Or set the background first and then overlay the retrieved image?

Comment: Create a new `BufferedImage`, fill it's background with the desired color and then draw the image over the top of it

Comment: Oh, I'd use `setColor` and `fillRect` instead, personally

Comment: Should I use the drawImage() method to draw my image on top of the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- Load your image

```
image = ImageIO.read(url) ;
```

2- Create a new `BufferedImage` of the same size

```
BufferedImage background =
    new BufferedImage(
        image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB
    );
```

3- Fill the `background` image with the desired color

```
Graphics2D g2d = background.createGraphics();
g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g2d.fillRect(0, 0, background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
```

4- Draw the original image onto the background...

```
g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
g2d.dispose();
```

`background` is now filled with the desired color and has the image painted on top o it.